# Passing audio chunk queues to Google's asynchronous transcribe option

Tags: python, asynchronous, queue, multiprocessing, google-speech-api

I am trying to pass audio chunks obtained using `chunks.get(in_data)` from PyAudio's callback function to [Google Speech's asynchronous transcribe](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize).

In addition, I am using Python's `multiprocessing` module to process these chunks one by one using `Threadpool` with a single worker:

```
pool = ThreadPool(processes=1, initializer=initGoogleCloud, initargs=(audio_rate, credentials_json, lang_code, asr_narrowband, preferred_phrases, show_all))  
async_result = pool.apply_async(GoogleCloud, (self.detect_chunk_buffer.get()))
return_text = async_result.get()
```

```
def initGoogleCloud(SAMPLERATE, credentials_json, lang_code, is_narrowband, preferred_phrases, show_all):
    assert isinstance(lang_code, str), "lang_code must be a string."
    try:
        from google.cloud import speech
        from google.cloud.speech import enums
        from google.cloud.speech import types
        from google.oauth2 import service_account
    except ImportError:
        print('google.cloud failed to import.')

    if is_narrowband is True:
        use_enhanced = True
        model = 'phone_call'
    else:
        use_enhanced = False
        model = 'default'

    # Configurations for Google Cloud
    with open('tmp_credentials.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(credentials_json, fp)
    google_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('tmp_credentials.json')

    client = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=google_credentials)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=SAMPLERATE,
        language_code=lang_code,
        use_enhanced=use_enhanced,
        model=model)
    streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config, interim_results=True)

def GoogleCloud(audio_chunk):
    byte_chunk = b''.join(audio_chunk)
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(byte_chunk)
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    #Waiting for operation to complete...
    response = operation.result(timeout=90)

    # Processing response
    return listen_print_loop(responses)
```

**The output:** 
TypeError: GoogleCloud() takes 1 positional argument but 2048 were given
Abort trap: 6

Seem's like `chunk.get()` is extracting all the audio sequence as an argument. Is there a way to pass a single chunk in a queue to be processed?

My PyAudio format is `pyaudio.paInt16`.

Answer (score 0):

To "pack" the audio chunk into an argument, I modified
`async_result = pool.apply_async(GoogleCloud, (self.detect_chunk_buffer.get()))`

To
`audio_chunk = [self.detect_chunk_buffer.get()]` which packs it into a list before sending it as an argument of `async_result = pool.apply_async(rttASR.GoogleCloud, args=(audio_chunk))`.

It works and seems like my `self.detect_chunk_buffer.get()` (containing paInt16 audio chunk from the PyAudio callback of in_data) does not require any extra base64 encoding.